# TemplateEngine with xml input and xpath expressions

Tags: xml, xpath, template-engine

to put it blantly, I am searching for an offline template engine to apply information from a xml-database into special text-files using xpath syntax.

I'm not so good in text, and being explicit is easier with an example. So my `db.xml` looks like:

```
<root>
    <what name="pete" />
</root>
```

and `file.tmpl` looks something like (syntax made up):

```
This is a scratch-file.
<!--(for n in '/root/what/@name')-->
   whats name is @!n!@
<!--(else)-->
   no whats...
<!--(end)-->
```

So after calling `./tool -x db.xml -t file.tmpl > file` the resulting content of `file` should be:

```
This is a scratch-file
   whats name is pete
```

Of course I wish for exceptions when the xpath returns a non-string in a variable context `@!!@` for example, and so on. I'm looking for data and model safety rather than performance or convenience.

I know: In the end this looks a lot like simplified xslt wrapped into a nice human-readable syntax ;-)

I did not find a template-engine tool which fulfills this. All I looked into use yaml/json as data input like mustache, django, pyratemp... Or do not provide a nice outer interface like django-xml.

I could begin rolling my own, but this feels just pointless, there are so many template engines already! Are there any pointers or inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed many templating languages available already that may suit your needs, but [SO policy does not allow asking for tools or libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as that would often solicit opinionated answers.

> I know: In the end this looks a lot like simplified xslt wrapped into a nice human-readable syntax ;-)

I personally think XSLT is very human-readable, as it uses XML, which itself is designed to be human-readable. But of course that is just a matter of opinion.

That said, I think with existing tools in the XML group of languages (XQuery, XSLT, XProc, XPath etc), you should be able to get a long way without too much effort. For instance:

- XSLT 3.0 ([a list of XSLT 3.0 processors can be found on the XSLT info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info)) allows you to write Text Value Templates, which is syntax embedded in text nodes, simply by using curly braces. To take your example input:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="/" expand-text="yes">
      This is a scratch-file.
      {for $n in /root/what/@name
         return 'whats name is ' || $n}
      {if(not(/root/what/@name)) then 'no whats' else ()}
  </xsl:template>
  ```

  or (also XSLT 3.0):

  ```
  <xsl:template match="/" expand-text="yes">
      This is a scratch-file.
      <xsl:sequence>
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/what/@name">whats name is {$n}</xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:on-empty>no whats</xsl:on-empty>
      </xsl:sequence>
  </xsl:template>
  ```
- Also with XSLT 3.0, you can use your example input with `xsl:evaluate` to automatically evaluate the XPath in your template. This will then not require your users to understand (some of) XSLT, and allows you all freedom in your template. You should, however, define a clear way of tokenizing your XPath from the rest (in your example, using comments is one way that works, as you can simply tokenize by `comment()` nodes).
- In XQuery 3.1, but this is hot of the press, you will have string templates, which go a lot further than XSLT. Using XQuery also has the advantage that it more naturally connects to existing XML databases. See [this thread for the modified propoposal](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xsl-query/2015Sep/0070.html) and following/preceding messages that lead to it.
- Using XProc you could pre-process your template, auto-generate XSLT, and have this XSLT as the main stylesheet for processing the actual output. With the new `xsl:initial-template`, it becomes trivial to design an entry point, and you can parameterize the input from your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... The links are very helpful! As to the off-topicness of the question: if someone could migrate it to superuser.com? I cannot ;-)

Comment: @klsdjfhsalkjfhl, the same "off-topicness" applies to superuser, so that won't help much. On XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, Saxon has a free community edition for home use, and we (I develop [Exselt](http://exselt.net)) are thinking of a free version for home use, but haven't decided on the particulars yet, as we are still in beta.

Comment: "free" and "free for home use" are completely different things. As long as there cannot be a Debian package, the software is essentially unreachable for me ;-) But "xmlpatterns" as part of Qt looks good. A lot of stuff to read up for me ;-)

Comment: @klsdjfhsalkjfhl I'm aware there are different definitions for "free". You are referring to a certain open source kind of license, of which many variants, often not compatible, exist. [QT has an XSLT 2.0](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0) version that is open source. A typical way forward in open-source world is to force the user to install his library of choice by hand or semi-automatic, in case you cannot bundle it with your software.

Comment: Oh, I see you already found Qt, good! But it won't have `xsl:evaluate` or other XSLT 3.0 specific things. Still, you should be able to get a long way and it may support some of the [EXSLT functions library](http://exslt.org/).

Comment: Sadly we cannot properly argue about licensing or packaging of software here, as the format of this comment thread is rather limited ;-)

Comment: @klsdjfhsalkjfhl Lol, true. But there exist a couple of threads elsewhere, i.e. on  the Programmers SE site it is very appropriate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl?sort=votes&pageSize=15